# I'm using Angular and I want to use *ngIf else (available since version 4) in this example

Tags: angular

i want to create a scenario  with 8 form on a single page; each form in a different section with a continue button. on the click of btn1 let section 1 be hidden and section 2 be visible and on the click btn 2 let section 2 and section 1 be hidden and section 3 be displayed and so on till the last form that carries the proceed and previous button `

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-job-score-target',
  templateUrl: './job-score-target.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './job-score-target.component.css' ]
} )
export class JobScoreTargetComponent implements OnInit
{
  siteUrl = 'http://stg-bpm.uacnplc.com/atb-appraisal'
  show: boolean = false;
  myForm: NgForm;
  section1: boolean = true;
  section2: boolean = false;
  section3: boolean = false;
  section4: boolean = false;
  section5: boolean = false;
  section6: boolean = false;
  section7: boolean = false;
  section8: boolean = false;
  constructor () { }

  ngOnInit ()
  {

  }
  onContinue ( section: string )
  {
    console.log( section );
    // this.reset();
    console.log( section );
    if ( section == 'section1' ) { this.section2 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section2' ) { this.section3 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section3' ) { this.section4 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section4' ) { this.section5 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section5' ) { this.section6 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section6' ) { this.section7 = true; }
    else if ( section == 'section7' ) { this.section8 = true; }


    // this.show;
    // console.log( this.show, 'show' )
  }
  reset ()
  {
    this.section1 = false;
    this.section2 = false;
    this.section3 = false;
    this.section4 = false;
    this.section5 = false;
    this.section6 = false;
    this.section7 = false;
    this.section8 = false;

  }
}
```

```css
h{
    text-align: center;
}

button{ 
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h6>Employee Target Scoring</h6>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form #f="ngForm">
            <div id="1"class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section1">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Attitude & Professional Appearance </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Exude a Positive Image </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Helpful, open and acommodating </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Giving Attention to details </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ability to Multitask, Followup and Follow through </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Punctuality and attendance</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Discipline and Morals </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Relationship with Superior,peer, surbodinate </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn1" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section2')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section2==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Customer Service and Relationship Mgt. </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Excellent communication and interpersonal skill</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Treat all Clients (internal & External) with respect </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Timely Response to Clients (internal & External) needs </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Building rapport and trust with clients </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Creating in-road and good will for ATB with clients</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button  id="btn2" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section3')" style="float:right">Continue</button>

            </div>
            <div id="3" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section3==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Operations </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contribute to the effective daily operation</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maintaining work equipments</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ensure smooth running of the business</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn3" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section4')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section4==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Business Documentations </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Keep accurate and complete records </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Saves time by making records available for others</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ensure daily backup </td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ensure source are saved as agreed in the team</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn4" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section5')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section5==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Team work & Communication </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ability to work positively with all teams </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Work in unity to achieve team's goals</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Going extra mile to achieve the Team's goal</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Communication: Oral & written</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn5" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section6')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section6==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Confidentiality </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maintain confidentiality on ATB issues</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maintain confidentiality on Clients issues</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maintain confidentiality on colleague issues </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Keeep content of confidential documents</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn6" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section7')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section7==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Personal & Professional Development </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Full attendance at scheduled trainings </td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Prepare for and write specified professional certifications</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Personal developments through books, short courses,& personal software projects</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Affilliation to relevant professional body</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn7" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue('section8')" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div id="8" class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="section8==true">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Understanding job role and expectation</th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Delivers duties as expected</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>interest, initiative, involvement & commitment to duties </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Performs job in the most cost effective manner </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contributes to the financial growth of the company</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <button class="success" type="button" style="float:right" routerLink="/achievement">Submit</button>
                <button class="success" type="button" style="float:right" routerLink="/job-description">Previous</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner if you implement a variable `currentStep` which is a number

```
export class JobScoreTargetComponent implements OnInit
{
  siteUrl = 'http://stg-bpm.uacnplc.com/atb-appraisal'
  show: boolean = false;
  myForm: NgForm;
  currentStep: number;

  constructor () { }

  ngOnInit ()
  {
      this.currentStep = 1;
  }
  onContinue (step: number)
  {
      this.currentStep = step
  }
  reset ()
  {
      this.currentStep = 1;
  }
}
```

Then your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="1"class="col-xs-12"  *ngIf="currentStep === 1">
                <table id="reorder" class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr style="background: beige;">
                        <th>Attitude & Professional Appearance </th>
                        <th>Max.Score</th>
                        <th>Score(Employee)</th>
                        <th>Score(Manager)</th>
                        <th>Reason for Scoring</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Exude a Positive Image </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Helpful, open and acommodating </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Giving Attention to details </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ability to Multitask, Followup and Follow through </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Punctuality and attendance</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Discipline and Morals </td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Relationship with Superior,peer, surbodinate </td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" style=" text-align: center"></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td rowspan="3">TOTAL:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="btn1" class="btn-block" type="button" (click)="onContinue(2)" style="float:right">Continue</button>
            </div>
```

And so on...

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooow! its working @ Baptiste Arnaud thanks a million time

Comment: No problem, I invite you to mark this answer as correct then :)